Настройка автоматический авторизации клиента в Keycloak
Всем привет!
Стоит задача: настроить бесшумную авторизацию для клиента Yandex-трекер и Kaspersky в Keycloak.
Клиент Yandex и клиент Kaspersky настроен по протоколу SAML..
Необходимо, чтобы когда пользователь открывает ссылку yandex-трекер или Kaspersky он автоматически бесшумно авторизовывался, то есть окно "ввода логина и пароля не было".
Сейчас настроено таким способом: Пользователь открывает браузер-переходит по ссылке клиента Yandex-вводит логин и пароль-авторизовывается. Если ему необходимо перейти например на Kaspersky, он переходит по ссылке и проходит бесшумная авторизация (окно ввода логина и пароля не требуется), то есть пользователь может бесшумно авторизовываться во всех клиентах. Как только он закрывает браузер и открывает заново, ему необходимо 1 раз "ввести логин и пароль" на любом клиенте.
Изучил много документации, не нашёл ответа на данный вопрос.
Предположил, что данная процедура настраивается в каждом клиенте SAML, но не нашёл точный параметр.
Возможно, если я не ошибаюсь, можно как-то настроить через Kerberos.
Вот окно авторизации при первом входе, необходимо один раз авторизоваться.
Вот так настроена цепочка аутентификации для browser.


Алексей, подскажите пож-та, получилось у вас решить вопрос?) сейчас тоже бьюсь с таким же вопросом
